# Compare vlaue in django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I want to compare a value in Templete if it is same insert data in database and else if value is False hide this div. how to add this else conditon too. so I can hide this div

```
 {% if {{DB_product_query.exec_summary}} == 'True' %}
   <div class="form-group row">
   <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Executive summary</label>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
     {{ form.executive_summary }}
    </div>
   </div>
 {% endif %}
```

Error::: **Could not parse the remainder: '{{DB_product_query.exec_summary}}' from {{DB_product_query.exec_summary}}'**

already checked DB_product_query.exec_summary return True

Comment: What is the value of `exec_summary`? Is it boolean or string?

Comment: it is boolean..

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove inner double curly brackets:

```
{% if DB_product_query.exec_summary == 'True' %}
```

Comment: Okay. It worked. and I update the question. can you tell me how can I use else condition here like else it is False hide this div

Comment: If condition is false, it will hide div automatically. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if

Comment: and with this if I removed  inner double curly brackets it does not return true and print as it is.

Comment: Try to:
{% if DB_product_query.exec_summary  %}

Comment: Nothing. still same

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If DB_product_query.exec_summary is false/empty, it should not show this div. It does not do that?

Comment: Since the value is `boolean`, not `string` remove `== 'True'` at all or is `is true` syntax https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#is-operator